# Determining type of effects in a mixed effect model

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

I am trying to fit a nonlinear mixed effects model, and here is my train of thought. So my model (I'm thinking) should be:

$Y_{ij} = f(\theta_i, t_{ij}) + \epsilon_{ij}$ where $f(\theta_i, t_{ij})$ is some nonlinear function.

In my data set, I have

1. **Time**: Number of days after disease is diagnosed (this varies from subject to subject. One person may have days 6, 10, 12, 30 and another may have 7, 8, 24, 88, etc.)

And for each entry of **Time**, I have:

2. **Bad Cell** Number of diseased cells (this should be my response,  $Y_{ij}$)
3. **Antibodies** Number of antibodies

So I'm thinking that #1, 3 should all be random effects? Because for **Time**, it's not consistent across all subjects, as each subject is measured at different time points. And **Antibodies** as my covariate also varies across different subjects, so it would make sense to treat it as a random effect. Now, it appears that there is no fixed effect in my model. So is my model reduced to a random effects model?